# Google BigQuery: Select and group by "yyyy-mm" from date field ("yyyy-mm-dd") or timestamp

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I would like to group by "yyyy-mm" from a date field ("yyyy-mm-dd") or timestamp field so that I can pull and group transactional data over multiple years without having to pull separate queries grouping by month for each year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(STRING(YEAR(timestamp)),'-',RIGHT(STRING(100 + MONTH(timestamp)), 2)) AS yyyymm,
  <any aggregations here>
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY 1
```

another option:

```
SELECT 
  STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(timestamp, "%Y-%m") AS yyyymm,
  <any aggregations here>
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY 1
```

both versions should work with timestamp or date

Comment: Is this for standard sql or for legacy sql?

Comment: that was in times of Legacy SQL - so it is for Legacy

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for Standard SQL:

```
SELECT concat(cast(format_date("%E4Y", cast(current_date() as date)) as string),'-',cast(format_date("%m", cast(current_date() as date)) as string)) as yyyymm, <other aggregations>
FROM <YourTable>
GROUP BY 1;
```

Just replace the current_date() with your column name containing the timestamp.